# angular stops working after HttpErrorResponse

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-services

I'm working with angular 8 and NodeJS server with mongo as my db.
I want to ask the client if he logged of without finishing his shopping cart if he wants to continue
or start a new shopping cart. the problem is when a turn a cart status from 'active: true' to 'active: false' and do a validation that the NodeJS cant call this cart anymore I get in the angular after the service call i get an HttpErrorResponse and every thing in the .subscribe() doesn't work.

**nodeJs route**

```
 router.get("/getCartDetails", async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const userId = ObjectID(req.headers.user._id);
    let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId, active: true });
    if (!cart) return res.status(404).send("no active carts were found"); // no matter what I send I get an HttpErrorResponse 404 //
    res.status(201).send(cart);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(404).send("no active carts were found");
}
```

});

**code part in angular component**

```
enter code here
 this.cartService.getCartDetails().subscribe(result => { // nothing works in subscribe//
        if (result) {
          this.cartID = res._id;
          this.modalService.open(this.content);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(["/products"])
        }      
      })
```

**cart service code part**

```
getCartDetails(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/cart/getCartDetails`)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're explicitly sending `404` status. In that case the HTTP observable would emit an `error` notification and not a `next` notification. And at the moment there is no error handling in the subscription.

Try to add `error` callback in the subscription

```js
this.cartService.getCartDetails().subscribe({
  next: (result: any) => {
    if (result) {
      this.cartID = res._id;
      this.modalService.open(this.content);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(["/products"])
    }      
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    console.log('Got error:', error);
    // do what you want when an error is emitted
  }
});
```

Comment: it works but the console is still full of errors not including the console.log('Got error:', error);

Comment: Could you please show what the error is? A screenshot would be better

Comment: zone-evergreen.js:2952 GET http://localhost:4000/cart/getCartDetails 404 (Not Found) a lot of this unfortunately I cant add a picture

Comment: the problem I send just a message and not the cart thank you for the help